# Are there templates for user messages utilizing twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I would like to use twitter bootstrap for my web site. It looks great but now I need to add messages of users (like those on forums or twitter). In other words it should display short text, submission time, image of the user, maybe some elements for voting.

Are there already css templates for such elements?

Comment: The closest to what you want looks-wise is probably popover. But nothing specifically as you would like i know of

Comment: Can you be more specific? you can create any html5 with tb. Sites like https://wrapbootstrap.com/ sell templates.

Comment: Isn't this OT? It's an open-ended request better adressed to search engines or forums, not a programming question.

Comment: Roman, seeing as you reference Twitter, and you're talking about front-end components… Have you considered copy-pasting the markup and CSS from Twitter? It's surprisingly easy with Chrome web inspector (right click > inspect element > copy as HTML; observe styles on the right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing you'll find "built in" to Bootstrap is the "Media Object".

```html
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    My text
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#media

You'll need to add the extra elements yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides the `alert` class:

```
<div class="alert">
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Example warning!
</div>
```

If you include the JavaScript from Bootstrap, then you can get a close button:

```
<div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Example warning!
</div>
```

It also has a number of colors (default is orange, you can add classes that will make it red, green, or blue).

The [docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#alerts) contain further details.